# Decrypt from AES-ECB ciphertext created with php/mcrypt using node.js

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, aes

I have an encrypted message using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, ECB mode, and Base64, I've tried decrypting using crypto(https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto) with the following code:

```
var text = '';
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-ecb","SOMEKEYHEREWITHLENGTH32ooooooooo", '');
text += decipher.update(data, "base64");
text += decipher.final();
```

The error I've been getting is: Invalid key length 32.

What should the length of key be? When I attempt to use 16 instead the error thrown is:
'TypeError: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt'

If client requires to use ECB with key of length 32, how can I make this case valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES is a subset of Rijndael with a fixed block size 128 bit whereas Rijndael supports block sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bit. The `128` in `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` means the block size. The `128` in `aes-128-ecb` on the other hand means the key size. Both AES and Rijndael support key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bit.

If you have a 32 character key and this key is not hex-encoded to reach those 32 characters then it is possible that you actually want `aes-256-ecb`.

Keep in mind that the key encoding might be different than the one in PHP so might need to parse the key into a `Buffer` with a specific encoding.

---

Also, **please don't use ECB mode**. It is insecure. You should use at least CBC mode with a random IV. Since the IV does not need to be secret, you can simply send it along with the ciphertext as a prefix for example. You would then need to slice it off before decryption.

Comment: Additionally, [unauthenticated encryption is dangerous](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).